# Swift didSet does not fire

Tags: swift, computed-properties, didset

Suppose I have class ExerciseSet with 3 properties: id, name, isEnabled.

I have an array of objects of this class:

```
var exerciseSets: [ExerciseSet] = [] {
    didSet {
        ExerciseSet.syncWithPList(updatedSets: exerciseSets)
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the code I do the following:

```
exerciseSets[index].isEnabled = !exerciseSets[index].isEnabled
```

But didSet would not fire in this case. Only if I write like this:

```
let set = exerciseSets[index]
set.isEnabled = !set.isEnabled
exerciseSets[index] = set
```

Why is it so? Can I somehow use the former option? The latter one seems to verbose, I hate it.

Comment: Make ExerciseSet a struct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why is it so?

`didSet` fires when you change **value of the property**, in example it would be when array itself changes.

Here

```
exerciseSets[index].isEnabled = !exerciseSets[index].isEnabled
```

you **change property of some object in the array, but array stays the same**, and contains same objects. So `didSet` won't be called.

## Can I somehow use the former option?

No, you can't. Use latter.

EDIT: I checked @martin-r advice to use structs for `ExerciseSet`, and it works, `didSet` set is called. Because when property value change for structure basically means creation of new structure with all but changed field being copied.

Answer (score 2):

That is most probably because `ExerciseSet` is a class, which means it is a reference type.

Just think of reference types variables as storing numbers. These numbers then point to where the actual `ExerciseSet` is located in memory. In other words `[ExerciseSet]` is essentially an array of numbers.

When you do this:

```
exerciseSets[index].isEnabled = !exerciseSets[index].isEnabled
```

You did not change any of the "numbers" in the array. You only looked for the "number" at a particular index, and you use that "number" to find the `ExerciseSet` object. After that, you set a property of the `ExerciseSet`.

As you can see, you did not modify the "number" in the array at all!

On the other hand, your second piece of code calls the `didSet` because you're telling it to throw away the element at a particular index and put the "number" that points to `set` at that index. Since you're tsking out an element of the array and putting something back in, you're *changing* the array itself! Therefore, `didSet` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Hate is a strong word :)

In this line:

```
exerciseSets[index].isEnabled = !exerciseSets[index].isEnabled
```

you're not actually changing anything *directly* in your `exerciseSets` array, you are changing something on *a specific* `ExerciseSet` item in that array.

Compare that to:

```
let set = exerciseSets[index]
set.isEnabled = !set.isEnabled
exerciseSets[index] = set
```

Here you are changing *an actual item* in your `exerciseSets` array and therefore `didSet` is fired.

Can you do something about it? Good question :) You need to update the `exerciseSets` array in some way or another to force the `didSet` so I don't think you can do it a lot shorter than the three lines above. I hope I am wrong though.

Yeah, not so much an answer as a comment, hope you can use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `didSet` trigger applies to the set, but not to its contents. In other words, *changing what objects are stored in the set* triggers the block, but *changing the objects’ contents* doesn’t. That’s why your first option doesn’t work and the second one does.